# Using win32com to control Excel and I need to update the color of Data Points but they seem to be read only

Tags: python, excel

```
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(f"C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\EXCEL\\Credits_Query.xlsx")
ws=wb.Sheets("OEM Pivot")
chart = ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart
chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues
```

Returns: ('NTK553FAE5', '8DG62496AA', 'TOM-100G-Q-LR4', 'ORM-CXH1', ...)

```
chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB
```

Returns: 39423

But it appears to be readonly.

```
>>> chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 50
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 590, in __setattr__
args, defArgs = self._prop_map_put_[attr]
KeyError: 'RGB'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\jepal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 592, in __setattr__
raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.ChartColorFormat 
instance at 0x2231402656864>' object has no attribute 'RGB'
```

I also tried several variations of:
chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB.**setattr**

But no luck, is it possible to change the color of the Data Points?

Answer (score 0):

As usual, hours of researching with no luck, and 2 min after I post I find the answer.

```
chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(3).Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 47
```

This allows you to change the color of the individual points.